# Add a class to a nabar modal in a component Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, modal-dialog

I wanted to know how can I add a class to a modal in a navbar components? My navbar is in App.vue and I wanted to create a message  that would add the class "is-active" to a modal in my navbar when I click on it. But I can't find the way to do that..

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when you have a `parent -> child` relationship you can use `events`. In this case since you have two components that are not linked (directly) then you have two alternatives.

**Using store**  (it is usually used in cases where your application is of a considerate size)

You can use [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) to have a central place where you will have your global state. A simple example would be:

*store/main.js*

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    isModalOpen: false
  },
  getters: {
    isModalOpen => (state) => state.isModalOpen,
  },
  mutations: {
    setIsModalOpen (state, isOpen) {
        state.isModalOpen = isOpen;
    }
  }
})
```

then you can access the store in your component as such:

```
<template>
  <navbar :class="[isNavBarOpen ? "is-active" : ""]" />
</template>

export default {
  computed: {
     isNavBarOpen () {
        this.$store.getters['isModalOpen']
     }
  }
}
```

**Event bus** (it is usually used in cases where you have a small app and do not need a global state manager)

Read more about EventBus [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-global-event-bus).

You can create a simple `EventBus`

*services/eventBus.js*

```
import Vue from 'vue';

const export EventBus = new Vue();
```

then on your component when the modal is open you can do:

```
// @ -> is an alias to your root folder. Most projects scafolded by Vue CLI has this by default
import {EventBus} from "@/services/eventBus"

export default {
  methods: {
    openStore: () => {
       // your logic to open modal
       EventBus.$emit('modal-open');
    }
  }
}
```

then on your `App.vue` you just listen to this event

*App.vue*

```
<template>
  <navbar :class="[isModalOpen ? "is-active" : ""]" />
</template>

// @ -> is an alias to your root folder. Most projects scafolded by Vue CLI has this by default
import {EventBus} from "@/services/eventBus"

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      isModalOpen: false,   
    }
  },
  created() {
     EventBus.$on('modal-open', this.onModalOpen);
  },
  methods: {
     onModalOpen() {
       this.isModalOpen = true;
     }
  }
}
```

The one you will pick depends on our application structure and if you think it is complex enough to use a central state management (vuex).

There might contain some errors in the code but the main idea is there.

Comment: Thank you very much it solve my problem !